# GitLab CI Prevent Merge Request from being merged when Downstream pipeline fails

Tags: gitlab

I'm using GitLab Enterprise Edition 16.0.0-pre

**Setup**

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
merge_request_pipeline:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"'
      when: always
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab/.merge-request-pipeline.yaml
```

`.gitlab/.merge-request-pipeline.yaml`

```yaml
tf_init_dev:
  environment: 'DEV'
  image:
    name: "hashicorp/terraform:1.4.6"
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - terraform init
  tags:
    - gitlab-org-docker
```

The project is configured so that pipelines must succeed for merge requests (Settings > Merge requests):
[image]

**Problem**
When I create a Merge Request, the pipeline is triggered as expected, and so is the downstream pipeline

But when the Downstream pipeline fails, I'm still allowed to merge the merge request.

[image]

**Questions**

- Is this the expected behaviour?
- If not, how can I configured the repo or the pipeline so the merge request isn't allowed to be merged even when the downstream pipeline fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, there is a `strategy` keyword which can tells GitLab that the parent job depends on the downstream pipeline:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
merge_request_pipeline:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"'
      when: always
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include: .gitlab/.merge-request-pipeline.yaml
```